# Ephemeral close reason

Tags: support

A few days ago I saw a question with this comment:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you have a
>   couple of very descriptive error messages and your question doesn't
>   show any research effort or steps you've taken to resolve those
>   issues.

I wanted to vote to close this question also, for the same reason, and I was surprised to discover that this exact reason existed.

I've selected this reason.

But this reason only existed for this specific question, while I was thinking that an update has been done.

This `voting to close` reason was from a very high rated member, so I am thinking that they have privilege to close a given question with an ephemeral reason.

I know this has already been discussed, and it is not the goal on this post, but `lack of research` is a good reason to close, and should be proposed by default (IMHO).

My questions are:

- Were my eyes tired or did I see right? (grrr I should have take a screenshot)
- Can you confirm that high rated members can add an ephemeral close
  reason for a given question that does not appear in the standard/usual close form?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Anyone with the [close votes privilege](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/close-questions) can make up their own close reason by selecting "Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)". The reason is also posted as a comment, and other users can then select it as the close reason, but only on that post.

This has been available for [nearly two years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/189912) now.

Comment: Well sorry...i should have read the user guide...mean "Read that f*** manual !" :)

Answer (score 8):

If you type in a custom off-topic reason, that reason will be available for anyone else to use.  I can't test it right now, but I'm pretty sure multiple custom reasons can be seen if different close-voters type them in.

Here, go to this question: [Push code from GitHub to (suppose) GoDaddy automatically](https://serverfault.com/questions/658060/push-code-from-github-to-suppose-godaddy-automatically)  Vote to close it as off-topic, and you should see what I just typed in.  But don't select that, pick "other" at the bottom and type in a close reason.